# Map couldn't be dragged while using Leaflet-side-by-side plugin in Vue2leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

Trying to use leaflet-side-by-side plugin in Vue2Leaflet.

```
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.map = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject;
      this.layer1 = this.$refs.leftLayer.mapObject;
      this.layer2 = this.$refs.rightLayer.mapObject;
      L.control.sideBySide(this.layer1, this.layer2).addTo(this.map);
    });
  }
```

This works fine in PC and android browser, but in iOS, the map couldn't be dragged(for both safari and chrome for iOS).
After removing the layer2, the map can be dragged again.

```
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.map = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject;
      this.layer1 = this.$refs.leftLayer.mapObject;
      // this.layer2 = this.$refs.rightLayer.mapObject;
      L.control.sideBySide(this.layer1, this.layer2).addTo(this.map);
    });
  }
```

Is this the proper way to use this plugin in Vue2leaflet?

Well, after deep study, this is one of the bug in leaflet-side-by-side. 
Still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 <LMap
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      @update:center="centerUpdated"
      ref="map"
      :watch="true"
      :options="{ zoomControl: false, dragging: mobileDragg, tap: mobileTap }"
   >
```

Methods:

```
// Leaflet mobile fix
mobileDragg() {
  return !L.Browser.mobile;
},
// Leaflet mobile fix
mobileTap() {
  return !L.Browser.mobile;
},
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work with 'leaflet-side-by-side' either.